# Unable to Open Software center nor Update Manager on 12.04

Tags: software-center, update-manager

When I try to install software I get this:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I keep being told to enter `apt-get -f install` but when I do I get this message:

```
owner@owner-1005HA:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

So, I need help with what it means and how to fix this.

Comment: “are you root?” You need root privileges to run the command, so prefix with sudo and post any results back here. Edit your question and add the results. (not in comment)

Answer (score 0):

Please try these commands:

```
    sudo killall dpkg
    sudo apt-get -f install
```

and let us know if that helps. It could be that update manager or software center was interrupted while it was used, causing dpkg to remain open.